# hide some content for mobile device

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

***i use `ngtable`:***

```
...
<td data-title="'Recherche par Marque'" filter="{ 'Marque': 'select' }" filter-data="names($column)"
...
```

I want to hide the data-title when my app is running under mobile device.
I know i do use [responsive-utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) but i don't know were i can put the class .hidden-xs`..?

i want only hide the `data-title`

Comment: Add a class to the td <td class='hidden-xs' ...>

Comment: adding `class="hidden-xs"` is not possible?

Comment: @DonJuwe it's not possible because it's hide the `td` i want only hide the `data-title`

Answer (score 1):

You could add two `<td>` elements with and without your title and show them by using classes to hide and show:

```
<td class="hidden-xs" data-title="'Recherche par Marque'" filter="{ 'Marque': 'select' }" filter-data="names($column)">
<td class="visible-xs" filter="{ 'Marque': 'select' }" filter-data="names($column)">
```

This will show the `td` with title if greater than `xs` and shows the other one without your title when `xs`.

Comment: please create a fiddle. this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mercer "two td now" that's ok, they are mutually exclusive since only one will be visible at a time, depending on the size of the screen.